# Get + in url instead of omitting by space

Tags: spring, rest, jersey

I have an api which searches nearby users by its location and Blood Group.
Api url is

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users/search?userLatitude=23.3&userLongitude=232.3&bloodGroup=B+
```

Whenever I am requesting it in postman, I am finding the + is omitted and blank space in the query parameter.  so what am i getting is that `bloodGroup=B`
my code is below:

```
@GET
@Path("/search")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response searchByBloodGroup(
        @QueryParam("userLatitude") String userLatitude,
        @QueryParam("userLongitude") String userLongitude,
        @QueryParam("bloodGroup") String bloodGroup) {
    logger.debug(">> searchByBloodGroup({},{},{},{})", userLatitude, userLongitude, bloodGroup);

    Map<Object, Object> apiResponse = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    Map<Object, Object> response = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

How can i avoid this situation?

**UPDATE**

> Requesting with
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/api/users/search?userLatitude=23.3&userLongitude=232.3&bloodGroup=B%2F
> ```
>
> get me `bloodGroup=B/` but with &bloodGroup=B%2B gives me
>   `bloodGroup=B` !!!

Comment: You should encode the URL in UTF-8,  + should be replaced with %2B

Comment: I suspect it is something that postman is doing perhaps. I just created the simplest MVC controller to echo the parameter back and the plus is displayed when encoded as %2B in the URL. Perhaps try the same with cURL or even just in a browser.

Comment: @Strelok I did with browser but facing the same issue. Can you check the update i wrote? 
it is horrible

Comment: why don't you use string instead of sign , like use "positive" instead of +. :-p

Comment: Yeah currently using that. Which i have to manipulate in client side. But dont want to. The problem is eating me. :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the URL if you are sending special characters. 
Use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode your URL string with special characters.

http://localhost:8080/api/users/search?userLatitude=23.3&userLongitude=232.3&bloodGroup="+URLEncoder.encode("+","UTF-8")